# how to connect to secure hbase cluster using SQuirreL SQL

Tags: security, hadoop, hbase, squirrel-sql, apache-phoenix

I am trying to setup SQuirreL SQL client to connect to secure hbase cluster deployed on CDH5.4.3.

I have copied kerberos keytab file, `hbase-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` in `lib` directory of SQuirreL SQL. I am using phoenix-4.3.0-client containing all required jars.

The connection URL format used is:

```
jdbc:phoenix:[quorum]:[port]:[rootNode]:[principal]:[keytab]
```

Below is the error from SQuirreL's logs:

```
2015-08-19 18:24:57,696 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - getMaster attempt 1 of 35 failed; retrying after sleep of 100, exception=com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=abc.xyz.com/10.201.15.151:60000]
2015-08-19 18:24:58,386 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - getMaster attempt 2 of 35 failed; retrying after sleep of 200, exception=com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: abc.xyz.com/10.201.15.151:60000
2015-08-19 18:24:59,176 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation  - getMaster attempt 3 of 35 failed; retrying after sleep of 300, exception=com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: abc.xyz.com/10.201.15.151:60000
```

Am I missing anything? Can anybody share the steps for setting up SQuirreL SQL to connect to secure `hbasecluster`?

Comment: were you able to connect finally?